# O que aconteceu com minha conta do stackoverflow?

Tags: debate, stackexchange

Hoje de manhã (**3:20**) fui entrar na minha conta do **stackoverflow** e minha conta (*ledevwd*) não estava logada e estava me pedindo para mim logar na conta, a minha conta foi logada anteriormente usando a do *Google* (*gmail*), mas ao tentar logar na minha conta foi especificado para mim criar uma nova conta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esperei um pouco para ver se isso sumia (**10:15**), mas não sumiu, então decidi em clicar no botão de criar nova conta (*Confirm new account*) subsequente isso iria criar uma nova conta encima da anterior, mas eu não tinha o que fazer. E quando entrei na minha "nova conta" minha reputação estava para **1** e tinha notificações dos comentários no inbox:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei entrar em algumas das minhas perguntas e respostas que eu fiz / dei recentemente e meu perfil estava como **user181348**:

[Hoisting ocorre com a variável dentro da função ou qualquer outro comando de bloco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/443595/hoisting-ocorre-com-a-vari%C3%A1vel-dentro-da-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ou-qualquer-outro-comando-de-blo/443608#443608)

[Alinhar texto ao centro da imagem - Bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/440800/alinhar-texto-ao-centro-da-imagem-bootstrap/440863?noredirect=1#comment850443_440863)

O que aconteceu com minha conta? ela foi suspensa, banida, excluída , se esse for o caso porque isso aconteceu?

Answer (score 9):

Não são permitidas novas contas para contornar suspensões anteriores ou restrições de sistema, e por isso a conta foi removida.

A criação de novas contas neste caso acaba resultando em remoção e/ou bloqueio enquanto não passar o período das restrições existentes, como já informado em mensagens privativas.

Sempre que é enviada uma mensagem particular de moderação ou *staff* da rede, abre-se espaço para um questionamento pelo mesmo mecanismo, de forma registrada e auditada, acessível aos moderadores e gerentes de comunidades da empresa, e é o canal adequado para tratar de problemas individuais, não relacionados ao funcionamento do site.